# Obmenu wont start: says I am missing the GTK module

Tags: arch-linux, openbox, gtk

When I type obmenu into the terminal I get an ImportError

```
    Import Error: No module name gtk
```

Here is the output of

```
    sudo pacman -Qs | grep "gtk" ::

   local/gtk-update-icon-cache 3.16.5-1
   local/gtk2 2.24.28-1
   local/gtk3 3.16.5-1
   local/pygtk 2.24.0-5
   local/transmission-gtk 2.84-1
   local/webkitgtk2 2.4.9-1
   local/wxgtk 3.0.2-4
   local/wxgtk2.8 2.8.12.1-3
```

Why would I be getting these errors even with GTK installed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install python-glade2 and python-gtk2 packages.